# For Python/MySQL, how do you perform a SELECT query on previous results?

Tags: python, mysql, filtering

```
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'myuser', password = 'mypass', host = 'localhost', database = 'mydatabase')

# Cursor for the connection
myCursor = myConnection.cursor()   

# Assume namecolumn is a valid column...
myQuery = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = Erik"
myCursor.execute(myQuery)

# Now here, do another SELECT, but only on the results that are in myCursor
```

So, lets say you have a table called 'mytable'. This table also has a column called 'name'. Lets say also that there are multiple people with the name 'erik' for the column 'name'.

What I am asking is that after doing the first SELECT query, is it possible to do another SELECT query, but ONLY on the existing results of the first query? If this is possible, how? Basically, I just want to use SELECT to filter the results repeatedly.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to run the same exact query on the results of your first query?

Comment: Let's say there's a better way to ask a question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think what you really want to do is running multiple filters on one set, as opposed to running select to run on smaller and smaller results repeatedly. simply add `and` and/or `or` statements to your `SELECT` clause

Answer (score 0):

Either add " and..." to the original query or create a list of ids from the first and select "where id in (...)" where ... is a comma delimited list of ids returned by the first query.

Comment: something I've always asked myself. when does the comma delimited list become too large to be used in an `where id in (...)` filter? Is there a maximum?

Comment: If there is a hard-coded limit, I've never come across it. It's not particularly fast or efficient but it uses the same internal structures as the massive sets of results returned by partial queries so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try more than one condition in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = 'Erik' AND born = 1990
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
myQuery = "SELECT * 
           FROM mytable
           WHERE name = 'Erik' 
           AND id in (SELECT DISTINCT id
                      FROM mytable)"
```

Getting distinct `id` or whatever other column you settle on will filter records so you avoid multiple records for the same person. It's hard to give a concrete answer given that your question is a bit vague.